bug on download a zip when the a tag contains download attribute with value true
I'm trying to download a zip file with the code:
async downloadZipFile( ) {
    await this.thankYouBtn.waitFor( { state: 'attached' }, { timeout: 5000 } );
    const downloadPromise = this.page.waitForEvent( 'download', { timeout: 10000 } );
    await this.closeOneTrustCookiePopup();
    await this.thankYouBtn.click();
    const download = await downloadPromise;
    await download.saveAs( '.' + download.suggestedFilename() );
}

and I'm getting the error :
Error: download.saveAs: File not found on disk. Check download.failure() for details.

and the a tag contains attribute: download=true
I want to verify the download of the zip file, and I'm expecting that the download will work without that error.

Please share a runnable, complete [mcve]. Thanks.
